# filter a user list view that is bind to observable array in knocout.js model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have a an observable array in my model that is bind to just a list of div's in the view, i want to create a textbox above that list which will filter out the users, like if i write: "admin" will only show users with name admin in them.

how do i do that in knockout? where should i keep the original list of users?
and how should i filter the observable array ?

my model looks like this: 
the observable array is usersWithGroups

```
var groupsViewModelClass = function () {
var self = this;
ko.mapping.fromJS({
    assignedPermissions: [],
    avilablePermissions: [],
    usersWithGroups: [],
    allGroups: []
}, {}, self);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ko.utils.arrayFilter` function

Example:

```
//filter the items using the filter text
viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        return this.items();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), filter);
        });
    }
}, viewModel);
```

See also: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: _note: `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` is not exported in the minified KO file. The code is simple enough though to replicate._ What's the deal with that?

Comment: `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` is used only as an example of function that can be used with `arrayFilter`. The main idea is that function within `arrayFilter` must check boolean condition for each `item` from collection and return `true` or `false`